# PDAL readers.ept fails to save LAS file

Tags: lidar, usgs, pdal

I am attempting to access the USGS 3DEP LiDAR Point Clouds - Registry of Open Data on AWS via the EPT PDAL reader in Python. I normally work with Python notation, so my code looks like this:

```
extent = gdf.total_bounds
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = extent[0], extent[1], extent[2], extent[3]
bbox = ([minx, maxx], [miny, maxy])

print("PDAL pipeline")
pipeline = (
    pdal.Reader.ept(filename=awslink, bounds=str(bbox))
    |pdal.Writer.las(lasout)
)
print("Executing pipeline to download USGS lidar data")
pipeline.execute()
```

Where awslink is the link to the resource and gdf is a geodataframe from which I extract the bounding boxes of the polygons I am interested in. Just like in the readers.ept example from the PDAL documentation:

```
[
   {
      "type": "readers.ept",
      "filename": "http://na.entwine.io/nyc/ept.json",
      "bounds": "([-8242669, -8242529], [4966549, 4966674])"
   },
   "statue-of-liberty.las"
]
```

However, when I apply the entire function, the writers.las saves a LAS file that is actually empty.

I've tried the same syntax with readers.las from a local LAS file and it works, so the issue is related to the readers.ept part. There is no error message, the code works, it just saves an empty file.

Comment: *UPDATE*: the issue was the projection of the boundaries. Apparently, the CRS to look for data and stream has to be WGS84 Pseudo Mercator - EPSG:3857. Once I reprojected the shapefile to that CRS, the Python-embedded pipeline worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the NYC data has moved. It is now located at https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/usgs-lidar-public/NY_NewYorkCity/ept.json and you can view that online at https://viewer.copc.io/?q=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/usgs-lidar-public/NY_NewYorkCity/ept.json

Comment: Thank you. But I was not using NYC in my code, I am actually using https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/usgs-lidar-public/USGS_LPC_GA_Georgia_A2_2016_LAS_2018/ept.json (and I've tried with others) and I get the result I mentioned.